# Change a question from "Deleted" to "Closed - transferred"

Tags: support, status-completed, migration

I recently removed (deleted) one of my own questions from Stack Overflow because I re-created the question under appropriate tags on Server Fault.

However, I hadn't realized that this would "permanently delete" the question from SO.

Ideally, I would have preferred the original question to just show a "CLOSED - Transferred to Server Fault" but it now appears completely deleted.

Can any admins help "undelete" my post ?

---

The "NEW" question is [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/114489/dns-server-ms-returns-nxdomain-original-returns-noerror)

Comment: I undeleted the question on SO, added a link to your SF question, then closed as NPR to prevent it from getting migrated again.  Sorry I didn't see this sooner.

Answer (score 4):

For future reference your best bet in that case is probably to flag for moderator attention and ask them to migrate (the term we use for moving questions between sites) it for you.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming migrated questions do not get deleted from their source site, your best bet right now is probably to take the following course of action:

1. Delete your Server Fault question (if this is possible, if not, skip this step.)
2. Undelete your Stack Overflow question.
3. Flag your Stack Overflow question for mod attention, and mention you want it migrated and MERGED into the Server Fault question (ID #114489).
4. Profit?!

This will get you the best of all worlds -- your SO question will be closed, but still visible and shown as migrated. The SF question you've already asked will get merged into the migration target, and you'll be set.

I'm not sure if migrated questions get deleted by the mods or not, though. If, as a matter of course, migrated questions get deleted from their source sites, then this may all be completely moot. If they do not, then this will get you everything you're looking for.

Comment: 1 - The Server Fault question now has active replies, so this is probably no longer suitable for deletion

2 - That is part of the problem - the system does not allow me to view (and hence undelete) it. [Original URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289518/dns-server-ms-returns-nxdomain-original-returns-noerror) 

3 - Depends on 2

Comment: Flag this question here for mod attention, point them to your original question, do steps 2 & 3. Be sure to give the mods the link to your old deleted question. I'd undelete it myself, but I don't have 10K rep and thus can't see it either. :)